# Adding custom path to ruby gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using HostGator shared hosting and in the RubyGems section of the cPanel it shows:

```
You will need to add /home/popboard/ruby/gems to the include path. 
You can do this by adding the following code to your script:
$:.push("/home/popboard/ruby/gems")
```

Where do I put that push script in a rails app for it to find those user installed gems?

Thanks!